# loop through array - add value returned from promise to each object in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, promise

basically, there's a small confusion I have.
I have an array of objects with each object having a person's name and the city that person is living in.

now, what I want to do is to loop through the whole array and get the distance of the city of each item in the loop from, say, California.

what I want to do is to use the city name to get the distance from california for that city and add it to each object in the array.

so, say item at index 1 has city Alabama, then I want the distance from Alabama to California and that as property distance to that item

like {name: John1, city:'Alabama', distance:'whatever the distance is'}

now, I have already done that using promise.allsettled but not sure if the order in which it is returning the data is same or mixed up so not sure if I am appending the correct distance to the correct item.

I am hoping that it returns things in the correct order and the way I have done it is correct, but if there's a better and cleaner way to do this, then I'd like to know how to do that.

## Here's the code too

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class GetDistance extends React.Component{
    state = {
        loggedInCity: 'Georgia',
        isLoading: false,
        projectsWithDistance:[],
        projects : [
            {
                name: 'John1',
                city: 'Alabama'
            },
            {
                name: 'John2',
                city: 'Arizona'
            },
            {
                name: 'John3',
                city: 'California'
            }, 
            {
                name: 'John4',
                city: 'Colorado'
            },
            {
                name: 'John5',
                city: 'Connecticut'
            },
            {
                name: 'John',
                city: 'Florida'
            },
            {
                name: 'John6',
                city: 'Idaho'
            },
            {
                name: 'John7',
                city: 'Kansas'
            },
            {
                name: 'John8',
                city: 'Maine'
            },
            {
                name: 'John9',
                city: 'Hawaii'
            },
            
        ]
    }

    getDistance = (zipFrom, zipTo) => {   
        console.log('zipFrom : ',zipFrom);
        console.log('zipTo : ',zipTo);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
          axios.post('http://localhost:8080/getDistance',{
          zipcodeTo:zipTo,
          zipcodeFrom:zipFrom
        })
        .then((res)=>{
          console.log('res from get distance in reducer : ',res.data);
          resolve(res.data.distance);
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
          console.log('error from distance : ',err)
          reject('');
        });
        })
        
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        const projects = this.state.projects;
        const from = this.state.loggedInCity;
        const promisesArr = [];
        for(var i=0; i<projects.length;i++){
            let distance = 0;
            let to = projects[i].city;
            distance = this.getDistance(from,to);
            promisesArr.push(distance);
        }
        const results = await Promise.allSettled(promisesArr);
        console.log('results : ',results);
        const projectsWithDistance = [];
        for(var i=0; i<projects.length;i++){
            let newProject = _.cloneDeep(projects[i]);
            const distanceFromResult = results[i].value;
            newProject.distance = distanceFromResult;
            projectsWithDistance.push(newProject);
        }
        this.setState({
            isLoading:false,
            projectsWithDistance
        });
    }

    render(){
        const {projectsWithDistance,isLoading, loggedInCity} = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                {isLoading?<h1>'Loading...</h1>:''}
                {!isLoading && projectsWithDistance.length>0?projectsWithDistance.map((item)=>{
                    return <div>Distance between {loggedInCity} and {item.city} is {item.distance}</div>
                }):''}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `for` loop by `for..of` loop.

```
const results = []
for await (const project of projects){
  let distance = 0;
  let to = projects[i].city;
  this.getDistance(from,to).then(distance => results.push(distance))
}
```

The `for of` loop is asynchronous in nature. So this should get it done.

Comment: but I also wanted to append the distance that I get from this to the project object. how do I do that then?